# How to collate teams by a property of the leader, in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregate

I have a database with some users, who belong to teams. Each team has a leader. Each user has a subject.

I want to collate teams by the leader's subject.

My data looks like this:

```
db={
  "teams": [
    {
      _id: "t1",
      members: [
        {
          "_id": "u1",
          "leader": true
        },
        {
          "_id": "u2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "u3"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      _id: "t2",
      members: [
        {
          "_id": "u2",
          "leader": true
        },
        {
          "_id": "u4"
        }
      ],

    },
    {
      _id: "t3",
      members: [
        {
          "_id": "u1",
          "leader": true
        },
        {
          "_id": "u4"
        }
      ],

    },
    {
      _id: "t4",
      members: [
        {
          "_id": "u2",
          "leader": true
        }
      ],

    },

  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": "u1",
      "subject": "history"
    },
    {
      "_id": "u2",
      "subject": "maths"
    },
    {
      "_id": "u3",
      "subject": "geography"
    },
    {
      "_id": "u4",
      "subject": "french"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result I want is:

```
{
    "history": ["t1", "t3"],
    "maths": ["t2", "t4"]
}
```

I have an aggregation that gets me the _id of every leader, and from there I can get the result I want in stages, by first finding the subject of every leader, then going back through the projects and assigning a subject to each project based on the identify of the leader. It works but it is inelegant and I think it will be slow. It seems to me there should be some better way to do this, maybe something like a join?

Is there a nifty way to get the result I want from a single MongoDB operation?

Here is a Mongo Playground with my data:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/SIJv9-hVNzJ

Many thanks for any help.

Edit: my test data are confusing because '_id' is used in both collections, making it hard to unpack the answer. Here is an updated [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hbqN3_o8hkD) that uses different key names for each collection and helped me to understand the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should join your collections on `users._id` with a **`$lookup`**, and then transform value to key with **`$arrayToObject`** (introduced in Mongodb 3.4.4)

Here is a possible way to do this :

```
db.teams.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$members"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "members.leader": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "members._id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$users.subject",
      "team": {
        "$push": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id",
              v: "$team"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/TuEpMzHkI-0](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TuEpMzHkI-0)